# android Strings and if statement

Tags: android, string, if-statement

Im sure this is really simple but it bugging the hell out of me

I use the following code

```
    String name = Global.PicName2;
    String tempstr = name.substring(0, 3).trim();
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), tempstr, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    if (tempstr == "Sou"){Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Yes", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
```

Now the first Toast reports that tempstr is "Sou"
I have checked the lenght of the string and it is 3 characters long
I have trimmed any spaces

Yet it will not go through the if statement and toast yes

If I add the line

```
    tempstr="Sou";
```

after the first toast it goes through the if statement so that says its the tempstr that is wrong but I cant work out why

Its driving me nuts any ideas?

Any help appreciated

Mark

Comment: Not really an answer, buy have you tried .equals() ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/java-vs-equals-confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
 if(tempStr.equals("Sou")){

}
```

Comment: DUH!!! God I cant believe im such a Donut thanks to all of you who showed me im an idiot annoying thing is I have been stuck on this for an hour :-(

Answer (score 1):

Since you are looking for value equality check. You should use `tempstr.equals("Sou")`.

**==** operator checks for reference equality while **.equals()** checks for value equality.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, when the “==” operator is used to compare 2 objects, it checks to see if the objects refer to the same place in memory. In other words, it checks to see if the 2 object names are basically references to the same memory location. A very simple example will help clarify this:

http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/java-questions/java-whats-the-difference-between-equals-and/

// your not checking objects are in same in same or not

```
if (tempstr == "Sou") // ==” operator is used to compare 2 objects, 
{
   Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Yes", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

// Right

```
if(tempStr.equals("Sou")){

}
```

or

```
if(tempStr.equalsIgnoreCase("Sou")){ // you can ignoring case 

}
```

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_operators.htm